# How to make $_POST more secured?

Tags: php, security

This is a sample code that i got from Facebook Engineering page.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['name']) {
?>
    <span>Hello, <?=$_POST['name']?>.</span>
<?php 
} else {
?>
<form method="post">
What is your name?<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
}
```

It says that the above code is not secured because it is open to cross site scripting. the correct way is to pass the $_POST['name'] via htmlspecialchars(). However, they stated that it is poor programming practice.

Is always passing $_POST variable via a htmlspecialchars() inefficient?

I can't thought of any way to make it secure. They introduce XHP which i am reluctant to use.

Reference: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/xhp-a-new-way-to-write-php/294003943919

Comment: I would recommend to follow this question [Best Way to stop Sql Injection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Don't see what this has to do with SQL injection at all. Derek, I suggest you read this - http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Comment: @Derek Also, they don't say using `htmlspecialchars()` is *poor practice*, just that it *might* be better to use something that escapes HTML output by default. I would recommend [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) over that `echo` mess in XHP though.

Comment: Thanks Phil, i think i misread it.. @MoyedAnsari reading that now.

Answer (score 0):

> the correct way is to pass the $_POST['name'] via htmlspecialchars(). However, they stated that it is poor programming practice.

It's not poor practice in itself. The problem is that when you have to type `htmlspecialchars` every single time you drop text content into HTML, you are quite likely to forget one, leaving a vulnerability.

What that page is saying, correctly, is that it's better to have a templating language that HTML-escapes *by default*, so that you don't have to think about it. This is a lesson most web frameworks have learned by now, but raw PHP still doesn't have a convenient way to do that.