# how to make an mail to form work

Tags: php, html, css, email, forums

I know it has been asked a lot on this website but i just need to know how to do it.

I've got a code in html on **CSS3** for an e-mail form. The only thing that is left for me is to make it work. My website is on the same server as my e-mail.

This is the coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
</head>
<body>
<form class="contact_form" action="#" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  placeholder="John Doe" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="website">Website:</label>
            <input type="url" name="website" placeholder="http://johndoe.com" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* === Remove input autofocus webkit === */
*:focus {outline: none;}

/* === Form Typography === */
body {font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;}
.contact_form h2, .contact_form label {font-family:Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;}
.form_hint, .required_notification {font-size: 11px;}

/* === List Styles === */
.contact_form ul {
    width:750px;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.contact_form li{
    padding:12px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    position:relative;
} 
.contact_form li:first-child, .contact_form li:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #777;
}

/* === Form Header === */
.contact_form h2 {
    margin:0;
    display: inline;
}
.required_notification {
    color:#d45252; 
    margin:5px 0 0 0; 
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}

/* === Form Elements === */
.contact_form label {
    width:150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
}
.contact_form input {
    height:20px; 
    width:220px; 
    padding:5px 8px;
}
.contact_form textarea {padding:8px; width:300px;}
.contact_form button {margin-left:156px;}

    /* form element visual styles */
    .contact_form input, .contact_form textarea { 
        border:1px solid #aaa;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
        border-radius:2px;
        padding-right:30px;
        -moz-transition: padding .25s; 
        -webkit-transition: padding .25s; 
        -o-transition: padding .25s;
        transition: padding .25s;
    }
    .contact_form input:focus, .contact_form textarea:focus {
        background: #fff; 
        border:1px solid #555; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa; 
        padding-right:70px;
    }

/* === HTML5 validation styles === */   
.contact_form input:required, .contact_form textarea:required {
    background: #fff url(images/red_asterisk.png) no-repeat 98% center;
}
.contact_form input:required:valid, .contact_form textarea:required:valid {
    background: #fff url(images/valid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
.contact_form input:focus:invalid, .contact_form textarea:focus:invalid {
    background: #fff url(images/invalid.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
}

/* === Form hints === */
.form_hint {
    background: #d45252;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: white;
    margin-left:8px;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    z-index: 999; /* hints stay above all other elements */
    position: absolute; /* allows proper formatting if hint is two lines */
    display: none;
}
.form_hint::before {
    content: "\25C0";
    color:#d45252;
    position: absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:-6px;
}
.contact_form input:focus + .form_hint {display: inline;}
.contact_form input:required:valid + .form_hint {background: #28921f;}
.contact_form input:required:valid + .form_hint::before {color:#28921f;}

/* === Button Style === */
button.submit {
    background-color: #68b12f;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#68b12f), to(#50911e));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    border: 1px solid #509111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5b992b;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #396715;
}
button.submit:hover {
    opacity:.85;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
button.submit:active {
    border: 1px solid #20911e;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #356b0b inset;

}
```

If some one can help me out it would be a blast.

Comment: You will need a server-side script (written in PHP for example) to process the data and send the email.

Comment: Are you running this page on a server that can run code such as PHP? You need a script that you can send the form fields to that is responsible for taking those fields and sending the email.

Comment: yes ive got an server that kan run anything bud i prefer php @MichaelShimmins do you got an solution becaus im net experienced enough to make the code my self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I created the **PHP** code that tested and worked.

Firstly replace your **HTML** cede with this

```
<form class="contact_form" action="submit.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="John Doe" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="website">Website:</label>
            <input name="website" type="url" name="website" placeholder="http://johndoe.com" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Your **CSS** will be the same and **PHP** code is this:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'your@email.com';
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n" .'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject = $subject;

$body.='Name: '.$name."\n";
$body.='Email: '.$email."\n";
$body.='Website: '.$website."\n";
$body.='Message: '."\n".$message."\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    die('Mail sent');
} 
else {
    die('Error: Mail failed');
}
?>
```

In `$to` on **PHP** write your email.

Note: You need to write **PHP** code on `submit.php`

Comment: @roXon: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/php-mail-header-injection-prevention

Comment: @PleaseStand I know that, my concern was just about the way to give answers regarding *PHP* by just saying *"go with it"* without warning the OP and not taking in consideration attacks while using forms (an open window to your nice server).

Comment: This is not secure at all!

Comment: @Enve, adding `session_start()` does not magically solve header injection attacks.. So, no, this form is not secure in the least bit. You need to sanitize the `$_POST` vars.

Comment: the script works on my test server. @Enve what is the best wy to moake the php secure

Comment: Read this post here http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476863/how-to-make-post-more-secured